# NIFI:Using Attributes inside groovy code

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I have  flowfile  which is  named after:'LimitedExceed' and  i  have updated  it inside  my updateAttribute  code and  then i  want to use  it inside my groovy code ,but  this   expression   below doesn't seem  to work  what  should  i change  to make  it  work?:

```
def filename=flowFile.getAttribute('filename')
String name=filename as String;
f(name.equals('LimitExceded')){

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def filename = flowFile.getAttribute('filename')
if( filename == 'LimitExceded' ){
   ... 
}
```